# How to dynamically select suffix values from a column value using a table of selection values

Tags: mysql, sql-server, casting

**Primary issue:** I can't re-create two MySQL statements into MS Sql - because MS SQL for instance does not cast a value like '1g' into an integer value of 1 although MySQL seems to with the MySql statements I've created.

**My Situation:**
I have a data column from a table that contains a mix of numbers + suffix character values.  I have an another table of information about allowed suffix values.  I'm trying to accomplish these things:

1. Select primary_data rows that contain certain suffix values and a related data field value (using the external table and where clause)
2. Show the scrubbed number value as an integer (scrubbing w/out the suffix) for sorting purposes
3. Return the list of "missing" numbers between 26 and 1000 in rows of 10 columns (each column representing each digit 0-9 and numbers 1-25 are always unavailable)
4. Numbers already taken ("unavailable") are depicted with a tilde '~' and those "available" are shown as a number in their respective column

   **-Items 3 & 4 above are not at issue here** but are the why I need 1 & 2

**Explicit Data limitations:**

- No number (the number part) will be outside the range of (1-999)
- Allowed suffix values are all contained in the external table

**What I've tried:**

I have a MySQL version that works the way I want but I need to convert it to MS Sql. When I try to manually convert the MySQL statements to MS Sql, I get a failure to convert to int error (ie converting '1g' to int).  I have MS SQL instances of each data table noted below as MySQL schema, but I can't figure out how re-create MySQL statements into MS SQL because of cast errors occurring over the data.

The significant issue is the [primary_data].[No] field containing different length suffix values (so I can't just look at the last ending character.)

**What I'm looking for:**

What I really would like is a simple way to select against a column in a "like" way from a table (i.e. [primary_data].[No]) using values found in another table (i.e. [suffix_values].[allowedvalue]).  Alternatively, I would like some pointers on how to re-create the MySQL view and result query into valid MS Sql statements.

---

**Sample MySQL good Result** - clip showing numbers 20-99 (csv):

```
Ten's,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
20's,~,~,~,~,~,~,~,~,28,~
30's,~,~,~,33,34,~,~,~,~,39
40's,~,~,~,43,~,~,46,47,~,49
50's,50,51,~,~,~,~,~,~,58,59
60's,60,61,62,63,~,~,~,67,68,69
70's,~,71,~,~,~,~,76,~,78,79
80's,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,~,~
90's,90,91,92,~,~,95,~,97,98,99
```

**Example Data:**
**primary_data** (mock csv data)

```
Chapter,No,Additional1,Additional2,Additional8
South,96,,Name 1,2014
South,75od,One Day,Name 2,2014
South,88ee,South,Name 3,2014
South,77g,South,Name 4,2014
South,32g,South,Name 5,2014
South,34od,One Day,Name 6,2014
South,51ot,Old Timers,Name 7,2014
South,35e,South,Name 8,2014
South,42g,South,Name 9,2014
```

Noting the above sample rows, the expected result is that rows containing "g", "e", "ee" would cause a tilde in their respective numeric bucket.  All the other numbers would be shown in their respective bucket.

**Example Data:**
**suffix_values:** (csv)

```
Id,Chapter,Suffix,IsEnabled
1,South,g,1
2,Sierra,s,1
3,Bay,b,1
4,Reno,r,1
5,Valley,v,1
6,One Day,od,0
7,1st Eval,e,1
8,2nd Eval,ee,1
9,Old Timers,ot,0
```

---

MySql Schema for table: **primary_data**

```
CREATE TABLE `primary_data` (
  `Chapter` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `No` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Additional1` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Additional2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Additional8` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

MySql schema for table: **suffix_values**

```
CREATE TABLE `suffix_values` (
  `Id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Chapter` varchar(50) DEFAULT '',
  `allowed_suffix` char(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `IsEnabled` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

MySql Schema for table: **allowednumbers** (values 1 to 999)

```
CREATE TABLE `allowednumbers` (
  `Number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Number`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

MySql Schema for view: **vnumbers** (needs re-creation in MS Sql)

```
SELECT  `primary_data`.`Chapter` AS `Owner`,
    `primary_data`.`Additional1` AS `Chapter`,
    `primary_data`.`Additional8` AS `ThisYear`,
    CAST(`primary_data`.`No` AS UNSIGNED) AS `scrubbed_number`
FROM    `primary_data`
WHERE   (
        (`primary_data`.`Additional8` <> '')
        AND `primary_data`.`Additional1` IN (   
        SELECT `suffix_values`.`Chapter`
        FROM    `suffix_values`
        WHERE ((`suffix_values`.`isenabled` = 1)
        AND (`suffix_values`.`allowed_suffix` NOT IN ('e' , 'ee'))
        )
    )
)    
ORDER BY `primary_data`.`Additional1` , CAST(`primary_data`.`No` AS UNSIGNED)
```

MySql for **result query statement** (I placed constant values in the where clause for this post and also needs re-creation in MS Sql)

```
Select Tens,
CASE col0
 WHEN 0 Then '~'
 ELSE col0
 END '0',
CASE col1
 WHEN 0 Then '~'
 ELSE col1
 END '1',
CASE col2
 WHEN 0 Then '~'
 ELSE col2
 END '2',
CASE col3
 WHEN 0 Then '~'
 ELSE col3
 END '3',
CASE col4
 WHEN 0 Then '~'
 ELSE col4
 END '4',
CASE col5
 WHEN 0 Then '~'
 ELSE col5
 END '5',  
CASE col6
 WHEN 0 Then '~'
 ELSE col6
 END '6',
CASE col7
 WHEN 0 Then '~'
 ELSE col7
 END '7',
CASE col8
 WHEN 0 Then '~'
 ELSE col8
 END '8',
CASE col9
 WHEN 0 Then '~'
 ELSE col9
 END '9' 
From (
    Select Concat('',x.row,'0''s') as Tens,  
    sum(x.Col0) 'col0', 
    sum(x.Col1) 'col1', 
    sum(x.Col2) 'col2', 
    sum(x.Col3) 'col3', 
    sum(x.Col4) 'col4', 
    sum(x.Col5) 'col5', 
    sum(x.Col6) 'col6', 
    sum(x.Col7) 'col7', 
    sum(x.Col8) 'col8', 
    sum(x.Col9) 'col9' 
From (
Select Left(cast(a.Number as char(3)),Length(cast(a.Number as char(3)))-1) 'Row',  
CASE  Right(cast(a.Number as char(3)),1)
WHEN '0' then a.number
 Else 0
END 'Col0',
CASE  Right(cast(a.Number as char(3)),1)
WHEN '1' then a.number
 Else 0
END 'Col1',
CASE  Right(cast(a.Number as char(3)),1)
WHEN '2' then a.number 
 Else 0
END 'Col2',
CASE  Right(cast(a.Number as char(3)),1)
WHEN '3' then a.number 
 Else 0
END 'Col3',
CASE  Right(cast(a.Number as char(3)),1)
WHEN '4' then a.number 
 Else 0
END 'Col4',
CASE  Right(cast(a.Number as char(3)),1)
WHEN '5' then a.number 
 Else 0
END 'Col5',
CASE  Right(cast(a.Number as char(3)),1)
WHEN '6' then a.number 
 Else 0
END 'Col6',
CASE  Right(cast(a.Number as char(3)),1)
WHEN '7' then a.number 
 Else 0
END 'Col7',
CASE  Right(cast(a.Number as char(3)),1)  
WHEN '8' then a.number 
 Else 0
END 'Col8',
CASE  Right(cast(a.Number as char(3)),1)  
WHEN '9' then a.number 
 Else 0
END 'Col9'
From  allowednumbers as a
Where (a.Number Not Between 1 and 25) and a.Number NOT IN (
Select scrubbed_number 
From vnumbers as b 
Where (b.Owner='South' and b.Chapter='South') and b.ThisYear= '2014')
Order by Cast(Left(cast(a.Number as char(3)), Length(cast(a.Number as char(3)))-1) as unsigned) 
) as x
Group by x.Row
Order by Cast(x.Row as unsigned)
) as z
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with my prior answer... I found some data rows did not conform to my expectations... so I solved this with a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getnumberonly
(
    @p1 nvarchar(50)
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN   
Return
    case (patindex('%[a-z]%',@p1)) 
        when 0 then @p1 
        else 
            case (patindex('%[0-9]%',@p1)) 
                when 1 then  -- Numbers first
                    substring(@p1, patindex('%[0-9]%',@p1), len(@p1) - patindex('%[0-9]%',reverse(@p1)) + patindex('%[0-9]%',@p1)) 
                else 
                 dbo.getnumberonly(substring(@p1, patindex('%[0-9]%',@p1), len(@p1) - patindex('%[0-9]%',@p1)))
            end
    end
END
```